# Mocking global HTTP Request in Angular and Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an HTTP request in my run block.

I want to avoid using beforeEach in every single unit test.
Where can I set a global mock that will run in every unit test?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you simply avoid loading the application itself in your unit tests, and only load the modules that need to be loaded for your tests?

Comment: And what about unit test a directive?

Comment: Same thing. You load the modules that are needed for this directive, and not the whole app.

Comment: Alternatively you could move the code from a `run` block into a service and mock this service in your tests.

Comment: My questions is - How can I mock a service globally instead of before each test?